# How to use Solrnet to search multiple collection? C#

Tags: c#, solr, solrnet

Q1. How to use Solrnet to search multiple collection?

Q2. I created a method to add data to Solr,
And if i want to dynamic assign sechma add data to Solr,
how to modify it?

```
     public void SolrFeeder(SchemaFieldList DataList)
    {
        var solrFacility = new SolrNetFacility(SolrServer);
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddFacility("solr", solrFacility);
        var solr = container.Resolve<ISolrOperations<SchemaField>>();
        foreach (var item in DataList.SchemaFieldList)
        {
            solr.Add(item);
        }
        solr.Commit();
    }
```

Comment: Q2 has been fix 
can use  var solr = container.Resolve<ISolrOperations<object>>();

Answer (score 3):

The standard syntax for searching across collections is to provide the name of the collections in the query - i.e. if you're querying `collection1`, you can still append a parameter named `collection` which contains a list of the collections you want to search, `collection=collection1,collection2,collection3`.

You can [use the syntax for "Additional Parameters"](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Querying.md) in SolrNet to add custom arguments to a query:

```
ISolrOperations<Product> solr = ...
var products = solr.Query(SolrQuery.All, new QueryOptions {
    ExtraParams = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        {"collection", "collection1,collection2,collection3"}
    }
});
```